# how to change google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout line colour

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: show above picture to change activated colour]

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="E-Mail"
                android:textColorHint="@color/yellow"
                android:id="@+id/email_txtInput">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_edtTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/yellow"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I have written the above code and I apply this line but did not work.

app:boxStrokeColor="@color/yellow"